# Chrome devtools with Android and Windows XP, blank window

Tags: android, google-chrome, windows-xp, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to debug my website using the Chrome Devtools with my Android phone and my computer Windows XP SP3.

The installation worked perfectly, ADB extension is installed on Chrome, and I can access the list of pages opened from the "Inspection target".

From here, I get an issue. When I click "Inspect" to see the Chrome Devtools for the page, I get a blank page with nothing inside. I tried different websites and I get the same issue.

[image]

Is anyone already got this issue and know how to fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you hit a bug in DevTools. :/ I'm on the DevTools team and may be able to help, but first up..

We're not sure just yet but it might have something to do with **WinXP**.. Less than 1% of our users are on it,  it's not tested to̵o҉ frequently and.. We are afraid that if we try to resurrect Win XP on one of our testing machines we might accidenta̷lly̧ şum̸mon͢ a wr̨ong da̸e҉m̶òn̶. H͏Ę̛ ̶͡C̀͠O̴ME̵S͡.

Seriously, MSFT's Windows XP support is nearly dropped.

If you can help us... Please press <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+I</kbd> to open a debugger window on the empty debugger window, press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to open console and send us what you see there.

Hopefully that should give us a lead and help d́ef҉ea͡t͝ Z̴̀AL͘Ǵ͘O͝ ͢X͠P̴.

Comment: I'm not able to open the console. Even when I'm clicking ESC. It's an empty window.

Comment: hit ctrl-shift-i on that blank devtools window. (devtools on devtools). Then Esc.

Comment: (3) Uncaught ReferenceError: InspectorFrontendAPI is not defined -
Uncaught ReferenceError: WebInspector is not defined

Comment: me too getting blank page, and following are the errors i am getting in console Document was loaded from Application Cache with manifest chrome-devtools://devtools/remote/serve_rev/@170045/170045.manifest devtools.html:1
Application Cache Checking event devtools.html:1
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'setDockSide'
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'setAttachedWindow'
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<InspectorFrontendHost> has no method 'zoomFactor'

Comment: Application Cache NoUpdate event devtools.html:1
Application Cache Checking event devtools.html:1
Application Cache NoUpdate event devtools.html:1
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'setDockSide'
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'setAttachedWindow'

Comment: It's absolutely not just XP, I'm seeing errors and blank screen on Ubuntu 13.10, Chromium 33.0.1750.152

Comment: The 3 errors I get: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'setDockSide'
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'setAttachedWindow'
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<InspectorFrontendHost> has no method 'zoomFactor' inspector.js:9162

Comment: @PaulIrish Do I need to make a new bug report for this somewhere? Also in Win7 it never seems to work unless I have just (re)installed the driver, though that is most likely a Windows bug.

Comment: Make sure you're running Chrome 34 (update to latest). If you are and still have this bug, then report it at crbug.com yup! (But 34 will resolve your problem)

Comment: @PaulIrish This is still happening. Running Chrome 37.0.2062.124 on a MacBook Pro (Retina 15" late-2013, 2.3 GHz Intel Core i7) with Mavericks (10.9.4), connected to a Galaxy S4 (Android 4.3). Tried revoking USB debugging authorisations, unplugging and replugging the cable, and I've tried restarting Chrome with all extensions disabled just in case. The strangest thing is that remote debugging was working PERFECTLY fine earlier this year (around early-mid July), using the exact same device and cable as the one I'm using now. Could it be the fault of an Android or Chrome update installed since?