# InspectorFrontEndApi is not defined during chrome remote-debugging

Tags: android, google-chrome, ubuntu-12.04, google-chrome-devtools, chromium

I am trying to setup remote debugging for my devices. I followed https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging#remote-debug and everything worked almost fine. I can see the devices at `chrome://inspect` and control the browser tabs. However, when I try to "inspect" I see a blank page. I found [Chrome devtools with Android and Windows XP, blank window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18727782/chrome-devtools-with-android-and-windows-xp-blank-window) which illustrates my problem exactly. The only difference being, I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and am running the chrom{e,ium} packages provided from the ubuntu repository. I tried inspecting with both chromium (32.0.1700.102) and google-chrome (32.0.1700.107). In the terminal, I get the following errors:

```
[19681:19681:0215/183805:ERROR:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: InspectorFrontendAPI is not defined", source:  (1)
[19681:19681:0215/183805:ERROR:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: InspectorFrontendAPI is not defined", source:  (1)
[19681:19681:0215/183805:ERROR:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: InspectorFrontendAPI is not defined", source:  (1)
[19681:19681:0215/183805:ERROR:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: WebInspector is not defined", source:  (1)
```

I get the same errors in the developer console (After pressing Ctrl+Shift+I in the blank inspect page).

I have the latest Chrome Beta installed on both my devices.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Same issue. I am using OSX 10.7.5, Galaxy Note II running Android 4.1.2

Comment: I tried replacing the cable I was using to connect my devices and that solved the problem. I think it's a hardware problem. I still get the errors sometimes but disconnecting-and-reconnecting the cable works usually. Try it.

Also noteworthy was that I was using my devices on my bed which had a velvet sheet. When I move, it tends to build up a charge which interferes with the USB cable and I get the above error.

Answer (score 1):

It's problem about network. For example, GFW of china will stop the devTool js from being loaded.(If you use charles, you could find that most js request to google failed with status of 404)

VPN would solve this problem.